# Flume agent unable to deliver event

Tags: java, linux, apache, hbase, flume

I am having 3 agents. 1 is running on windows using memory channel and other 2 are on Linux using File Channel to get data from windows agent and put in to Hbase.

Can any one suggests why the following error occurs and what are the step to stop it?

```
2013-12-23 14:50:15,290 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUG - org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.destroyConnection(AvroSink.java:199)] Avro sinksink1 closing avro client: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: 192.168.101.232, port: 3001 }
2013-12-23 14:50:15,290 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)] Unable to deliver event.
Exception follows.org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Failed to send events
        at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.process(AvroSink.java:325)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: 192.168.101.232, port: 3001 }: Failed to send batch
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.appendBatch(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.process(AvroSink.java:309)        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: 192.168.101.232, port: 3001 }: Handshake timed out after 20000ms
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.appendBatch(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:280)
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.appendBatch(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:224)    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.appendBatch(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:278)
```

Following is my windows config file

```
a1.sources = source1
a1.channels = channel1 channel2
a1.sinks = sink1 sink2

a1.sources.source1.handler = com.flume.handler.DynamicJSONHandler
a1.sources.source1.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
a1.sources.source1.bind = 192.168.101.29
a1.sources.source1.port = 2001

a1.channels.channel1.type = org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel
a1.channels.channel1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000

a1.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink
a1.sinks.sink1.hostname = 192.168.101.232
a1.sinks.sink1.port = 3001

a1.channels.channel2.type = org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel
a1.channels.channel2.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.channel2.transactionCapacity = 1000

a1.sinks.sink2.type = org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink
a1.sinks.sink2.hostname = 192.168.101.233
a1.sinks.sink2.port = 3001

a1.sources.source1.channels = channel1 channel2
a1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
a1.sinks.sink2.channel = channel2
```

Answer (score 4):

AvroSink is meant to write data to another flume agent which has an Avro Source listening on that specific source. The Avro Sink initiates a handshake with the source it is connecting to. But it looks like that handshake is timing out after 20 seconds - so it is likely your network is facing major latency issues. Do you see any issues on the agent running the source?

Comment: At the same time i have not received any issue at my source agent.

Comment: But when i reduce the load on Avro Sink, the error disappeared. Thanks for reply

Comment: @Shah how you reduce the load can you explain please?